# How can I concatenate a number with the percentage symbol using sqldf package?

Tags: r, sqldf

Supose that my df is something like this:

```
k <- data.frame(x = c("a", "b","c"), y = c(12, 2, 8), z=c(120, 2, 10))
```

and I want to obtain something like this exclusively using sqldf:

```
x y  z    Perc
a 12 120  10% 
b 2  2    100%
c 8  10   80%
```

I tried something like this:

```
sqldf("select *, y/z*100||'%' as Perc from k")
```

but this doesn't add the percentage symbol. 
I really need to do it with sqldf.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to wrap it with `()`

```
sqldf("select *,  (y/z*100)|| '%' as Perc from k")
```